# javascript dom concatenate background-position string / auto update background image?

Tags: javascript, dom, string-concatenation, background-position

I seem to have trouble with this line:

```
back_x += 1;
back_y += 10;           

document.getElementById('body_id').style.backgroundPosition =  back_x + 'px ' + back_y + 'px';
```

.css file

```
body
{   
   background: #000;    
background-image:url('image.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px;
background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

`<BODY id = "body_id";  >`

Basically I'm trying to use Javascript to update the background image position which works only once within a loop and and doesn't work again thereafter. Everything else on the page runs fine. Could it be the string is not concatenated properly?

EDIT: After a couple of minutes my page runs fine then all JavaScript functions cease to work! =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem on your code.

But you can maybe test this:

```
function updatePositionBackground(x, y) {
   document.body.style.backgroundPosition = x + "px " + y+ "px";
}
```

A do a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/RN8mB/

You can see that the background position is correctly updated.

Comment: It does work but it only seems to update the background once and never again. Everything in my Javascript loop runs like before but the background position doesn't update.

Comment: It isn't the code that you given to us.

Please share the rest of your code if you would like some help.

Comment: The code I showed is most of the loop. There isn't much more to it but I'll post it soon.

Comment: Nevermind, it works now. I just realized that I put `var back_x = 0;
 var back_y = 0;` within the loop with the background position update!